# Как можно обратится к свойству объекта из вложенной функции (в javascript)?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть объект javascript. Внутри него есть обращение к одному из методов `jQuery`.
Слово `this`, в данном контексте указывает на объект `jQuery`.
Как можно добраться до свойства моего объекта?
Несколько строк кода пояснят лучше, что я имею в виду.

```
var form = new fillForm();

function fillForm(){
    this.value = '';  

  jQuery("#inp").on('change',function(){
    var v = jQuery(this).val();
    //Как присвоить свойству value объекта fillForm значение переменной v
    })

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ozq84hf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
var form = new fillForm();

function fillForm(){

    // ссылка на себя
    var self = this;

    this.value = '';  

  jQuery("#inp").on('change',function(){
    var v = jQuery(this).val();
    //Как присвоить свойству value объекта fillForm значение переменной 
    self.value = v;
    })

}
```